# How to integrate RFID with ERP

Tags: rfid, erp

We have built one ERP application, we need to implement RFID in our application. I don't have any idea on RFID Requirement. How to implement?

We have built application using Python.

I need some idea and requirement need to built RFID module.

Comment: 'RFID module': By this you mean a module in your Python application which will process RFID inputs. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes module in python , I am using odoo ERP, in this ERP we use XML and python, we declare field in python and created view in XML,like this we created one module,now i need to connect RFID with my ERP module.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works:
Your software --> rfid reader --> antenna --> rfid tag

Threat rfid reader as a server. You can query it about nearby tags using tcp connection. Every manufacturer provide api client to its readers.

From your module you just connect to rfid reader and read a tags table ( basically tag Id and time it was detected)